# How to get the interval between two time in query?

Tags: mysql

Can you please help me get the interval of these two column |clockin|clockout| in my database using mysql. I tried the timediff below but the problem is, example: i clock in 23:00:00 this evening of 09/22/16 and i clocked-out 01:00:00 of morning of 09/23/16, i get a wrong result which is -22:00:00 hrs? The result i need to get is the 02:00:00 hrs. Please help me.

`select timeDiff('clockout', 'clockin') as interval;`

Comment: I really need help on this please to those who have a wide knowledge in programming. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is simply that you need to add 24 hours under some circumstances:

```
select (case when clockout > clockin
             then timeDiff(clockout, clockin) 
             else addtime(timeDiff(clockout, clockin), '24:00:00')
        end) as diff
```

Comment: Thankyou Gordon Linoff, i'll try your answer, hope it will work.

Comment: I still got the wrong result the thing is mine returns negative your's is not which returns 22:00:00 hrs. What result i am trying to get is the 02:00:00 hrs.

Comment: @W.Jackson . . . I'm confused.  In the question you say that you get  -22 hours.  When you add 24 hours to that, you should be getting 2 hours.

Comment: Thanks W.Jackson it's working now, your code is working my fault i ddin't check my data that i put there..Thank you verry much.

Comment: Im new to Stack overflow is there anyway to like or vote you for helping me?

Comment: ahh ok..tnx again Gordon Linoff